# Do the proton PDFs change much with Q?

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, large-hadron-collider

Specifically, the second moments, do they change much from say 100 to 1000 GeV? Why or why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check directly yourself using the [Durham HEPData page](http://hepdata.cedar.ac.uk/pdf/pdf3.html), which lets you plot PDFs as a function of $x$ or $Q^2$.

At large $x = 0.1$, they're fairly constant over a range of $Q^2$.

[image: large-x PDFs]

But at small $x = 10^{-4}$, they rise quickly with $Q^2$:

[image: small-x PDFs]

This is an illustration of [Bjorken scaling](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/File:DIS-QCD.png) at large $x$ and its breaking at small $x$.

I'd also mention that the $Q^2$-dependence of the PDFs is predicted from QCD by the DGLAP equations, so you can look at those to further understand the behavior.

Answer (score 3):

As usual the review of particle physics has some useful figures.

From the [2011 edition the chapter on Structure Functions (PDF link)](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2011/reviews/rpp2011-rev-structure-functions.pdf) has this figure
[image]
which is not quite the bounds you asked for but does show considerable change.

Comment: Well they're at least qualitatively the same.. and that's over a 100x bigger range than I'm considering, so would it be a reasonable approximation to say they don't change much (say within 5-10%) from 10^2-10^3 GeV?