# Spatial configuration of quarks?

Tags: quarks

Is there anything known about the spatial configuration of the quarks within a proton of pion? Or are they just considered to be two or three overlapping points?

Answer (score 1):

The [parton distribution functions (PDFs)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/56005/do-the-proton-pdfs-change-much-with-q) are momentum distributions sorted by flavor. The Fourier transforms of them give you the position distributions.

You can get similar, though sometimes less specific (i.e. no flavor information) from the [form-factors](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/19886/where-to-find-cross-section-data-for-e-p-p-e) or structure functions.

---

See also: [What is an intuitive picture of the motion of nucleons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/35724/520) for the same kind question about the motion of the nucleons in the nucleus.

Comment: Do you have a link to the paper about a lattice simulation of quarks within proton? I vaguely recall a figure with Y-like strings with three quarks on the ends of them.

Comment: @firtree As far as I know that is not a serious visualization, but a casual representation that is about as accurate as the typical nucleus-with-three-ellipses-around-it drawing of an atom. And while I don't follow lattice QCD, last I heard a realistic simulation of a nucleon was still a goal. PDFs, structure functions and form-factors come from *data* except for the heavy quark mesons whee the lattice guys can do a good job.

Comment: More specifically: just a static proton, no other particles or something. It was a 3D plot of 2D spatial distibution of something, so I don't think it was a freehand draw. About middle of 2000s.